# how can i retrieve specific fields from object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, lodash

I want to retrieve a part of an JavaScript objet.

The final object should have all the **hits.hits._source** 
 I tried  different things with lodash or underscore but I did not get it

My inital object is

```
 {
     "took": 7,
     "timed_out": false,
     "_shards": {
         "total": 5,
         "successful": 5,
         "failed": 0
     },
     "hits": {
         "total": 3,
         "max_score": 1,
         "hits": [
             {
                 "_index": "users",
                 "_type": "user",
                 "_id": "1",
                 "_score": 1,
                 "_source": {
                     "id": "112",
                     "type": "pro",
                     "email": "liz@google.com"
                 }
             },
             {
                 "_index": "users",
                 "_type": "user",
                 "_id": "2",
                 "_score": 1,
                 "_source": {
                     "id": "2",
                     "type": "pro",
                     "email": "john@google.com"
                 }
             }
         ]
     }
 }
```

I want to get

```
[
    {
        "id": "112",
        "type": "pro",
        "email": "liz@google.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "pro",
        "email": "john@google.com"
    }
]
```

Comment: pluck "_source" from root.hits.hits

Comment: `b=[];for (i in a.hits.hits){b.push(a.hits.hits[i]._source)}` will get `b` as your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7jLz13n6/

You can do like this:

```
var output=[];
var input=o.hits.hits;
for(i=0;i<input.length;i++)
  output.push(input[i]._source);
console.log(output);
```